# Vibration and rotation energies in Schrodinger equation

Tags: schroedinger-equation

We can write Schrodinger equation as:

$$H\psi=E\psi$$

Suppose a simple system like hydrogen molecule $H_2$.

**Question:**

Is this what physics call electronic hamiltonian: $$\hat{H} = \hat{K}_e + \hat{K}_n + V_{ee}(r) + V_{en}(r,R) + V_{nn}(R)$$
or it isn't? And what about rotation and vibration for a simple system as $H_2$?

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically we calculate electronic structures using the [Born Oppenheimer approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born%E2%80%93Oppenheimer_approximation), so we ignore the vibrational and rotational motion. The calculation of the electronic energy as a function of nuclear separation then gives us the potential that we use for calculating the vibrational and rotational structure.

So the Hamiltonian we use for the electronic structure does not have any vibrational or rotational terms.

Comment: wow, great answer. So the curve with U form is an aproximmation and you can calculate $\frac{dU}{dcoord}$ to obtain the potential, or something like that?

Comment: Yes, though $dU/dx$ gives the force because the calculated $U$ is the potential energy.

Comment: And is it correct if I write: $$\Large\psi=\psi_{el}\psi_{nucl}\psi_{rot}\psi_{vib}\psi_{trasl}$$ ?

Comment: @HernanMiraola: well, that's the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. Strictly speaking the wavefunction isn't separable in that way, but the approximation is a very good one.

Comment: Good..and is right what I wrote or would you write: $$\Large\psi=\psi_{el}\psi_{rot}\psi_{vib}\psi_{trasl}$$?

Comment: What is $\psi_\text{trasl}$? Translational? If so we normally work in the centre of mass frame of the molecule so there is no translational term.

Comment: I am confused about the nuclear wavefunction and its hamiltonian. Would you write a small example as $H_2$?